# How do I install the Perforce client?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install perforce on my Ubuntu machine, after I untar the .tgz file, I get two folders lib and bin. Where would be the executable or how do I install it correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main binary will always be in the `bin` folder (hence the name bin(ary) :P). The program shouldn't need to be installed. Just double-click on the main binary or run

```
./nameofbinary
```

in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

run the p4v file in the bin folder.

```
./p4v
```

Or double click on the file and select run from the dialog.